# WCF Service FileNotFound exception after Key authorization implementation

Tags: c#, web-services, rest, wcf, api-key

I have written a WCF API. It runs (ran) just fine.
Now that I need to open it up to public access I tried to implement API Key verification following [the example of Ron Jacobs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rjacobs/2010/06/14/how-to-do-api-key-verification-for-rest-services-in-net-4/) and [the accompanying video on endpoint.tv](https://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Endpoint/endpointtv-How-to-do-API-Key-Verification-with-a-WCF-WebHttp-REST-service/)

This basically just uses a list of GUIDs stored in an xml file that represent the valid API keys. The authorization request key is passed via query string and validated in a custom ServiceAuthorizationManager like this:

```
protected override bool CheckAccessCore(OperationContext operationContext)
{
    return IsValidAPIKey(operationContext);
}

public static bool IsValidAPIKey(OperationContext operationContext)
{
    string key = TvinQuery.GetAPIKey(operationContext);

    Guid apiKey;

    // Convert the string into a Guid and validate it
    if (Guid.TryParse(key, out apiKey) && TvinQuery.APIKeys.Contains(apiKey))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

`TvinQuery.APIKeys`is a simple `List<string>` containing the valid guids from the xml file.

The solution compiles, but when I publish it on my server and try to access the service there, I get a FileNotFound exception for file or assembly "WCFWebHttp" or one of its dependencies.

The cause for this is very obviously this part in the service behavior node of web.config:

```
<serviceAuthorization serviceAuthorizationManagerType="WCFWebHttp.APIKeyAuthorization, WCFWebHttp" />
```

Unfortunately, neither a search through my assemblies nor through my file system nor an internet search nor a nuget package search came up with an assembly of that name.

Event viewer and enabled tracing did not reveal any further information either.

What is it? How can I solve this error? Is there anything wrong or missing with the example? It worked just fine in the video and that was a live presentation. :-?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As from this picture:

[image]

at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rjacobs/2010/06/14/how-to-do-api-key-verification-for-rest-services-in-net-4/

it looks like WCFWebHttp is an assembly implemented in the source code of the sample you've used (which I can't download right now to make sure because of server error).

Comment: I am such an idiot. Yes, this is simply the name of his project and `APIKeyAuthorization`the name of his custom ServiceAuthorizationManager class. *shame*. All I had to do was change it into `<serviceAuthorization serviceAuthorizationManagerType="TVIN_API.MySecurityManager, TVIN_API" />` according to my project name and class, and deactivate `aspNetCompatibilityEnabled` for me. Works now. Thanks!